# Get parameters of a parametric type

Tags: types, julia

Suppose I define a type like that

```
type Point{Tx, Ty} end
```

Then I create a variable of this type, for example,

```
a = Point{Int64, :something}()
```

Now, I only know that I can get the type of `a` by `typeof(a)`. That is, `Point{Int64, :something}`.
But, what I need is just the parameters `Tx` and `Ty`.

Are there ways that I can get those parameters `Tx` and `Ty`?

Comment: If you ever update the syntax to julia 1.0 ping me that I can update the answer.

Comment: Updated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962169/how-can-i-access-a-generic-type-parameter-when-it-hasnt-been-specified-in-the-f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function as follows

```
eltypes{Tx,Ty}(::Type{Point{Tx, Ty}}) = (Tx, Ty)
eltypes(p) = eltypes(typeof(p))
```

(here `::Type{Point{Tx, Ty}}` matches an argument of type `Point{Tx, Ty}`) and use it

```
julia> eltypes(Point{Int, Float64}())
(Int64,Float64)
```

This is a frequently used idiom, for example in Base there is the similar function

```
eltype{T}(::Type{Set{T}}) = T
eltype(x) = eltype(typeof(x))
```

Answer (score 7):

`typeof(a)` is a `DataType` which has many fields. you can get those names via:

```
julia> fieldnames(DataType)
10-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :name        
 :super       
 :parameters  
 :types       
 :instance    
 :size        
 :abstract    
 :mutable     
 :pointerfree 
 :ninitialized
```

so if you need those parameters, run

```
julia> collect(typeof(a).parameters)
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 Int64     
 :something
```