# How can I access a generic type parameter when it hasn't been specified in the function body?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have

```
struct X{T} end
```

and a function dispatching on `X`, how can I access `T` inside the function body if it hasn't been specified in the method signature? I.e.

```
function foo(x::X)
    # can i get T in here?
end
```

---

This is a rephrasing of a question from the julialang slack: https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C6A044SQH/p1568651904113000

To get access, simply fill this form: https://slackinvite.julialang.org

Comment: Crossref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759794/get-parameters-of-a-parametric-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to define an accessor function:

```
getparam(::X{T}) where {T} = T
```

and then one can do

```
function foo(x::X)
    T = getparam(x)
    ...
end
```

So long as you are not running julia through an interpreter, all the type checks should be elided away at compile time. For instance:

```
julia> foo(x::X) = getparam(x) + 1
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(X{1}())
2

julia> @code_llvm foo(X{1}())

;  @ REPL[24]:1 within `foo'
define i64 @julia_foo_19216() {
top:
  ret i64 2
}

julia> @code_llvm foo(X{2}())

;  @ REPL[24]:1 within `foo'
define i64 @julia_foo_19221() {
top:
  ret i64 3
}
```

As you may be able to see, the compiler was able to figure out that it can just replace the call `foo(X{2})` with `3` at compile time with no runtime overhead at all.

---

As a side note, this should serve to demonstrate why [type stability](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Write-"type-stable"-functions-1) is important. If we had done something like `foo(X{rand(Int)})`, the compiler wouldn't have access to the type parameter until it arrives at `foo` in runtime and then would need to compile a specific method for whatever `rand(Int)` ended up evaluating to, which would be very slow:

```
julia> @btime foo(X{rand(Int)}())
  2.305 ms (1962 allocations: 125.49 KiB)
-3712756042116422157
```

Oof, that is slooooow! For comparison,

```
julia> bar(x) = x + 1
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime bar(rand(Int))
  9.746 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5990190339309662951
```